# Changing navbar color depending on its position. Color not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, haml

I'm trying to change the color of my navbar depending on its position in the html doc. It changes to black at first, but it doesn't change again. Am I even calculating the position correctly? Here is the code.

```js
$(function () {
    console.log('Running from the navBar.js')

    var scrollStart = 0;
    var $navStartChange = $('nav');
    var $navChild = $('.navigation-flex');
    var offset = $navStartChange.offset();
    var $portfolioPos = $('section#portfolio').position();
    var $openSourcePos = $('section#openSource').position();


    $(document).scroll(function () {
        scrollStart = $(this).scrollTop();

        console.log('This is the position of the porfolio section: ' + $portfolioPos.top);

        console.log('This is the position of offset: ' + offset.top);

        if ( scrollStart >= $portfolioPos.top ) {
            console.log('Arrived at the top of the portfolio section');

            $navStartChange.css('position', 'fixed');

            $navChild.css('background-color', '#2c3e50');
        } else if ( scrollStart >= $openSourcePos.top ) {
            console.log('Arrived at the top of the openSource section');

            $navChild.css('background-color', 'green');
        }
    }) /* End of scroll function */ 

})
```

**main.haml**

```
 %nav
        %ul.navigation-flex
          %li
            %a.logo{href:"index.html"} Home
          %li
            %a{href: "#about"} About
          %li
            %a{href: "#portfolio"} Work
          %li
            %a{href: "#labs"} Labs
          %li
            %a{href: "#contact"} Contact
      %section#portfolio
        %article.article--fritmark
          .article--fritmark__img-container
            .window--outer.isHidden
              %span.btns
                %span.browser-red
                %span.browser-yellow
                %span.browser-green
              %span.newTab
              %img.article--fritmark__img{src: "/img/screenshoots/favs.png", alt: "favs" }/
      %section#openSource
        %h1.section-subheading Open Source Contributions
        %h1.section-subheading Github Chart
```

Comment: What syntax are you using for your HTML? Can you tag that please?

Comment: @sunny Patel it is haml

Comment: Is there a working sample to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, instead of attaching to the scroll event (which gets called a ridiculously enormous number of times in a very short timespan), attach to an interval (in my example below, the interval is every 5 milliseconds).

`getBoundingClientRect().top` is a good way to get the y position of an element in your page. jQuery has shortcuts I'm sure, but I just went for a vanilla JS solution here.

`document.body.scrollTop` is a good way to get the scroll position on the page. It compares well with the bounding rectangle top of elements on the page.

Let the following code serve as a code reference for you to be able to find an effective way to solve your particular problem.

```js
var nav = document.getElementById("nav"),
    about = document.getElementById("about"),
    work = document.getElementById("portfolio"),
    labs = document.getElementById("labs"),
    contact = document.getElementById("contact");

var aboutTop = about.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    workTop = work.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    labsTop = labs.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    contactTop = contact.getBoundingClientRect().top;

var scroller = setInterval(function() {
  var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
  var offset = 20; // So the color changes just a bit before reaching the position
  scrollTop = scrollTop + offset;
  
  if (scrollTop < aboutTop) {
    nav.style['background-color'] = "#f0f0f0";
  } else if (scrollTop<workTop && scrollTop>=aboutTop) {
    nav.style['background-color'] = "red"; 
  } else if (scrollTop<labsTop && scrollTop>=workTop) {
    nav.style['background-color'] = "green";
  } else if (scrollTop<contactTop && scrollTop>=labsTop) {
    nav.style['background-color'] = "black";
  } else if (scrollTop>=contactTop) {
    nav.style['background-color'] = "blue";
  }
}, 5);
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
nav {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.anchor {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -55px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#labs">Labs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
<a class="anchor" id="about"></a>
<section id="about-section">
<h1>About</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ipsum mi, auctor quis lobortis at, rutrum sed ante. Etiam ipsum nisi, lobortis eget sem non, iaculis consectetur diam. Vestibulum accumsan diam nec luctus lobortis. Donec rhoncus est vitae diam ultrices, at gravida purus ultrices. Morbi blandit enim turpis, sit amet aliquam urna convallis et. Proin eleifend, nibh non sodales hendrerit, massa ex consequat sem, vel cursus ante enim ac ex. Suspendisse pellentesque dui felis, non condimentum nunc vehicula vitae. Suspendisse laoreet, dui ut fringilla gravida, arcu quam pharetra erat, nec maximus enim leo quis nisl. Aliquam sit amet euismod mi. Pellentesque sollicitudin, arcu id malesuada facilisis, magna mi lobortis mi, sit amet dictum elit lorem sit amet augue. Praesent mauris tortor, ullamcorper in laoreet et, malesuada vel lectus.</p>
<p>Mauris quis tincidunt ipsum, id auctor dui. Phasellus vel quam quam. Nulla facilisi. Duis ullamcorper tempor varius. Praesent cursus venenatis libero vitae mattis. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus convallis ullamcorper condimentum. Fusce vel semper urna. Donec ac lacus magna. Sed imperdiet dolor ut urna accumsan hendrerit. Etiam ac ipsum vitae nisi egestas pellentesque. Ut vitae vestibulum purus. Aliquam aliquet tristique scelerisque.</p>
<p>Donec viverra hendrerit congue. Nam consequat justo non ligula feugiat, cursus hendrerit urna ornare. Pellentesque pellentesque metus non orci fringilla, id eleifend lectus pharetra. Integer scelerisque leo ex, sed imperdiet enim blandit a. Nam eget ante sit amet libero elementum vulputate in vitae velit. Ut quis lobortis sapien, nec volutpat neque. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc convallis mi et quam malesuada euismod. Mauris posuere massa odio, dictum venenatis tellus feugiat ut. Etiam bibendum tellus nulla, pretium venenatis erat pellentesque sed. Phasellus viverra eu enim non egestas. Nullam aliquam sed metus a volutpat.</p>
<p>Mauris quis eros non orci varius lacinia. Morbi aliquet consectetur neque malesuada tincidunt. Morbi ornare rhoncus risus. Mauris condimentum arcu vel tincidunt bibendum. Curabitur magna tortor, sollicitudin vitae dolor sit amet, lobortis luctus felis. Suspendisse potenti. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur nec enim ut elit pretium blandit eget convallis lacus. Suspendisse aliquet mattis tortor, nec tincidunt mauris suscipit at. Etiam pharetra lectus sed pharetra congue. Integer molestie arcu ut enim dignissim mollis. Mauris vitae luctus dolor, a sollicitudin magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nam enim felis, suscipit id felis lobortis, fringilla elementum erat. Praesent sagittis, sapien eu feugiat ultricies, mi metus egestas augue, vitae vulputate diam arcu vitae felis.</p>
<p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec eu pulvinar purus. Quisque dictum accumsan congue. Etiam mollis diam nulla, in vulputate dui blandit a. Aliquam diam libero, dignissim id erat vitae, laoreet semper eros. Fusce iaculis rhoncus leo, quis scelerisque metus placerat ac. Etiam tellus nunc, congue ac euismod ut, convallis eu velit.</p>
</section>
<a class="anchor" id="portfolio"></a>
<section id="portfolio-section">
<h1>Work</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ipsum mi, auctor quis lobortis at, rutrum sed ante. Etiam ipsum nisi, lobortis eget sem non, iaculis consectetur diam. Vestibulum accumsan diam nec luctus lobortis. Donec rhoncus est vitae diam ultrices, at gravida purus ultrices. Morbi blandit enim turpis, sit amet aliquam urna convallis et. Proin eleifend, nibh non sodales hendrerit, massa ex consequat sem, vel cursus ante enim ac ex. Suspendisse pellentesque dui felis, non condimentum nunc vehicula vitae. Suspendisse laoreet, dui ut fringilla gravida, arcu quam pharetra erat, nec maximus enim leo quis nisl. Aliquam sit amet euismod mi. Pellentesque sollicitudin, arcu id malesuada facilisis, magna mi lobortis mi, sit amet dictum elit lorem sit amet augue. Praesent mauris tortor, ullamcorper in laoreet et, malesuada vel lectus.</p>
<p>Mauris quis tincidunt ipsum, id auctor dui. Phasellus vel quam quam. Nulla facilisi. Duis ullamcorper tempor varius. Praesent cursus venenatis libero vitae mattis. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus convallis ullamcorper condimentum. Fusce vel semper urna. Donec ac lacus magna. Sed imperdiet dolor ut urna accumsan hendrerit. Etiam ac ipsum vitae nisi egestas pellentesque. Ut vitae vestibulum purus. Aliquam aliquet tristique scelerisque.</p>
<p>Donec viverra hendrerit congue. Nam consequat justo non ligula feugiat, cursus hendrerit urna ornare. Pellentesque pellentesque metus non orci fringilla, id eleifend lectus pharetra. Integer scelerisque leo ex, sed imperdiet enim blandit a. Nam eget ante sit amet libero elementum vulputate in vitae velit. Ut quis lobortis sapien, nec volutpat neque. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc convallis mi et quam malesuada euismod. Mauris posuere massa odio, dictum venenatis tellus feugiat ut. Etiam bibendum tellus nulla, pretium venenatis erat pellentesque sed. Phasellus viverra eu enim non egestas. Nullam aliquam sed metus a volutpat.</p>
<p>Mauris quis eros non orci varius lacinia. Morbi aliquet consectetur neque malesuada tincidunt. Morbi ornare rhoncus risus. Mauris condimentum arcu vel tincidunt bibendum. Curabitur magna tortor, sollicitudin vitae dolor sit amet, lobortis luctus felis. Suspendisse potenti. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur nec enim ut elit pretium blandit eget convallis lacus. Suspendisse aliquet mattis tortor, nec tincidunt mauris suscipit at. Etiam pharetra lectus sed pharetra congue. Integer molestie arcu ut enim dignissim mollis. Mauris vitae luctus dolor, a sollicitudin magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nam enim felis, suscipit id felis lobortis, fringilla elementum erat. Praesent sagittis, sapien eu feugiat ultricies, mi metus egestas augue, vitae vulputate diam arcu vitae felis.</p>
<p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec eu pulvinar purus. Quisque dictum accumsan congue. Etiam mollis diam nulla, in vulputate dui blandit a. Aliquam diam libero, dignissim id erat vitae, laoreet semper eros. Fusce iaculis rhoncus leo, quis scelerisque metus placerat ac. Etiam tellus nunc, congue ac euismod ut, convallis eu velit.</p>
</section>
<a class="anchor" id="labs"></a>
<section id="labs-section">
<h1>Labs</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ipsum mi, auctor quis lobortis at, rutrum sed ante. Etiam ipsum nisi, lobortis eget sem non, iaculis consectetur diam. Vestibulum accumsan diam nec luctus lobortis. Donec rhoncus est vitae diam ultrices, at gravida purus ultrices. Morbi blandit enim turpis, sit amet aliquam urna convallis et. Proin eleifend, nibh non sodales hendrerit, massa ex consequat sem, vel cursus ante enim ac ex. Suspendisse pellentesque dui felis, non condimentum nunc vehicula vitae. Suspendisse laoreet, dui ut fringilla gravida, arcu quam pharetra erat, nec maximus enim leo quis nisl. Aliquam sit amet euismod mi. Pellentesque sollicitudin, arcu id malesuada facilisis, magna mi lobortis mi, sit amet dictum elit lorem sit amet augue. Praesent mauris tortor, ullamcorper in laoreet et, malesuada vel lectus.</p>
<p>Mauris quis tincidunt ipsum, id auctor dui. Phasellus vel quam quam. Nulla facilisi. Duis ullamcorper tempor varius. Praesent cursus venenatis libero vitae mattis. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus convallis ullamcorper condimentum. Fusce vel semper urna. Donec ac lacus magna. Sed imperdiet dolor ut urna accumsan hendrerit. Etiam ac ipsum vitae nisi egestas pellentesque. Ut vitae vestibulum purus. Aliquam aliquet tristique scelerisque.</p>
<p>Donec viverra hendrerit congue. Nam consequat justo non ligula feugiat, cursus hendrerit urna ornare. Pellentesque pellentesque metus non orci fringilla, id eleifend lectus pharetra. Integer scelerisque leo ex, sed imperdiet enim blandit a. Nam eget ante sit amet libero elementum vulputate in vitae velit. Ut quis lobortis sapien, nec volutpat neque. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc convallis mi et quam malesuada euismod. Mauris posuere massa odio, dictum venenatis tellus feugiat ut. Etiam bibendum tellus nulla, pretium venenatis erat pellentesque sed. Phasellus viverra eu enim non egestas. Nullam aliquam sed metus a volutpat.</p>
<p>Mauris quis eros non orci varius lacinia. Morbi aliquet consectetur neque malesuada tincidunt. Morbi ornare rhoncus risus. Mauris condimentum arcu vel tincidunt bibendum. Curabitur magna tortor, sollicitudin vitae dolor sit amet, lobortis luctus felis. Suspendisse potenti. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur nec enim ut elit pretium blandit eget convallis lacus. Suspendisse aliquet mattis tortor, nec tincidunt mauris suscipit at. Etiam pharetra lectus sed pharetra congue. Integer molestie arcu ut enim dignissim mollis. Mauris vitae luctus dolor, a sollicitudin magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nam enim felis, suscipit id felis lobortis, fringilla elementum erat. Praesent sagittis, sapien eu feugiat ultricies, mi metus egestas augue, vitae vulputate diam arcu vitae felis.</p>
<p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec eu pulvinar purus. Quisque dictum accumsan congue. Etiam mollis diam nulla, in vulputate dui blandit a. Aliquam diam libero, dignissim id erat vitae, laoreet semper eros. Fusce iaculis rhoncus leo, quis scelerisque metus placerat ac. Etiam tellus nunc, congue ac euismod ut, convallis eu velit.</p>
</section>
<a class="anchor" id="contact"></a>
<section id="contact-section">
<h1>Contact</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ipsum mi, auctor quis lobortis at, rutrum sed ante. Etiam ipsum nisi, lobortis eget sem non, iaculis consectetur diam. Vestibulum accumsan diam nec luctus lobortis. Donec rhoncus est vitae diam ultrices, at gravida purus ultrices. Morbi blandit enim turpis, sit amet aliquam urna convallis et. Proin eleifend, nibh non sodales hendrerit, massa ex consequat sem, vel cursus ante enim ac ex. Suspendisse pellentesque dui felis, non condimentum nunc vehicula vitae. Suspendisse laoreet, dui ut fringilla gravida, arcu quam pharetra erat, nec maximus enim leo quis nisl. Aliquam sit amet euismod mi. Pellentesque sollicitudin, arcu id malesuada facilisis, magna mi lobortis mi, sit amet dictum elit lorem sit amet augue. Praesent mauris tortor, ullamcorper in laoreet et, malesuada vel lectus.</p>
<p>Mauris quis tincidunt ipsum, id auctor dui. Phasellus vel quam quam. Nulla facilisi. Duis ullamcorper tempor varius. Praesent cursus venenatis libero vitae mattis. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus convallis ullamcorper condimentum. Fusce vel semper urna. Donec ac lacus magna. Sed imperdiet dolor ut urna accumsan hendrerit. Etiam ac ipsum vitae nisi egestas pellentesque. Ut vitae vestibulum purus. Aliquam aliquet tristique scelerisque.</p>
<p>Donec viverra hendrerit congue. Nam consequat justo non ligula feugiat, cursus hendrerit urna ornare. Pellentesque pellentesque metus non orci fringilla, id eleifend lectus pharetra. Integer scelerisque leo ex, sed imperdiet enim blandit a. Nam eget ante sit amet libero elementum vulputate in vitae velit. Ut quis lobortis sapien, nec volutpat neque. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc convallis mi et quam malesuada euismod. Mauris posuere massa odio, dictum venenatis tellus feugiat ut. Etiam bibendum tellus nulla, pretium venenatis erat pellentesque sed. Phasellus viverra eu enim non egestas. Nullam aliquam sed metus a volutpat.</p>
<p>Mauris quis eros non orci varius lacinia. Morbi aliquet consectetur neque malesuada tincidunt. Morbi ornare rhoncus risus. Mauris condimentum arcu vel tincidunt bibendum. Curabitur magna tortor, sollicitudin vitae dolor sit amet, lobortis luctus felis. Suspendisse potenti. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur nec enim ut elit pretium blandit eget convallis lacus. Suspendisse aliquet mattis tortor, nec tincidunt mauris suscipit at. Etiam pharetra lectus sed pharetra congue. Integer molestie arcu ut enim dignissim mollis. Mauris vitae luctus dolor, a sollicitudin magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nam enim felis, suscipit id felis lobortis, fringilla elementum erat. Praesent sagittis, sapien eu feugiat ultricies, mi metus egestas augue, vitae vulputate diam arcu vitae felis.</p>
<p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec eu pulvinar purus. Quisque dictum accumsan congue. Etiam mollis diam nulla, in vulputate dui blandit a. Aliquam diam libero, dignissim id erat vitae, laoreet semper eros. Fusce iaculis rhoncus leo, quis scelerisque metus placerat ac. Etiam tellus nunc, congue ac euismod ut, convallis eu velit.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for.  I like the vanilla js. It gets me to practice both js and jquery. I'll change it to jquery. Thanks once again.